# Difference "all night" vs "all night long" in meaning

Tags: difference

Is there any practical difference between?

1. We were working all night
2. We were working all night long

Comment: On ELU: [Difference between all-the-night and all-night-long](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/is-there-any-difference-between-all-the-night-and-all-night-long); also: [All Day vs All Day Long](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131409/the-whole-day-all-day-or-all-day-long).

Comment: The latter is more likely to give you a [Lionel Richie earworm](https://youtu.be/vvKxqJQPyS8?t=59).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **long** there functions as a kind of intensifier. In both cases, your time-card will show the same punch-marks, but if you worked **all night long** you will be more tired.  :)

> His car alarm was going off all night long.

The car alarm was going off throughout the night. There were no significant stretches of time during which you had peace and quiet.